# Is it a good idea to use React.Context to inject UI-Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dependency-injection

I plan to build a react component library. The react components are UI-Components but should only implement a specific logic. I want the user to be able to define a set of atoms (basic react components) that are used to compose the actual components. My main goal is to make the library independent of a specific UI-Component-Library like MaterialUI, ChakraUI, etc.

My idea was to use a React.Context to inject the components like this:

```js
// Button Atom
const Button: FC = ({ children }) => (<button>{children}</button>)

const atoms = { button: Button }
const AtomContext = createContext(atoms);

// "higher" component
const HigherComponent: FC = () => {
  const atoms = useContext(AtomContext)
  // Logic ...

  return (
    <atoms.button>click me</atoms.button>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AtomContext.Provider value={atoms}>
      <HigherComponent />
    </AtomContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

This solves my problem. But I'm not sure if it is a good idea. Are there better ways to inject UI-dependencies? What may be problems with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that can result in multiple answers based on personal experience.

But overall the idea to pass component trough context is a bit of misuse of that concept.

Also it does not bring much benefit from making a standalone library that can be imported via `package.json` or making a folder with components and importing them.

If you need to pass some specific things to your components you can have a custom provider as you did there, but as far as the component themselves, there is no common sense to use context.

If you end goal is to shorten the list of imports of component with custom context hook and just getting them like that, I think that is a bad tradeoff overall.

Comment: Yes, it feels like a misuse of the concept. That is the reason for my question. Do you mean you don't see benefit compared to putting the atoms in a separate library and import them? I don't see how that solves the problem. If I have a package `@maltesar/atoms` and the actual library I want to build `@maltesar/highercomponents`, I cant change the atom imports in the second library from "outside", right?

Comment: Yes, i dont see much benefits in comparation to separated library or just having a folder with atoms and other components. If you want those components to be reusable than making separated library is a good solution. As for the second question if I understood you correctly you want to have all components inside `@maltesar/hightcomponents` and just use them from context and not have them imported?

Comment: right, I want to be able to pass any package implementing the atoms "interface" into the `@maltesar/hightcomponents` package. A (typed) context allows me to do that.

Comment: Well, in that case you can do what you planned. Still I think that is not the right way to use context, that is why we have importing of components from packages or simple components/atoms folder (collections), not passing them in context and getting them from context. I know that it is typed and you will get necessary linting and checks, but if it works for you go for it :)

Comment: Do you know a better solution? I cant say that i'm happy with the context solution. How can I inject either `@maltesar/atoms-a` or `@maltesar/atoms-b` or any other package of atoms as a dependency into `@maltesar/hightcomponents`? Should I open up a new question for that? Your really helped me to sharpen the actual question. Thanks :)

Comment: Yea, no problem. Well I cant think of another way to "inject" components like this. I am familiar with only making a package that you just import components from. In your case context should only be used to pass some common stuff. In Material UI for example you got theme provider that passes stuff that components will use as styles. So in your case if you need to pass something like that but not the components themselfs do that. I think that you should just think about changing your mindset on this topic, and not try to find a way to do injection. You can make new question regarding import

Answer (score 0):

I just read this [article](https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2021-03-19-react-context-for-dependency-injection-not-state/) about using react context for dependency injection. The authors opinion is, that react context for injecting non-react dependencies into components is good practice. However, I'm not sure if that applies to injecting a specific set of react components. Since, react components are nothing more than functions I think it should be alright to use reacts context for that.